# UFT API - Unable to run a POST in uft but working fine on postman - JSON

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14, uft-api

Hi I'm running a post request using UFT API test with a JSON file and it's throwing me an error 500 or aborted request

the thing is it works fine in postman in the same machine, is there anything that i should set or something in uft for it to work?

same headers set in both (uft and postman) and all...

tried removing some headers but nothing worked

a weird thing is that if i run the request in postman first and then use the same body (with the same data) in uft it works (but this wont generate the unique data i need in the response)

anyone faced something similar??